# affine vector space

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry, finite-geometry

In an article it is written that: 
 
"A well known result from the theory of Boolean functions is that if the algebraic degree of a Boolean functions is less than d, then the sum over the outputs of the function applied to all elements of an affine vector space of dimension $\geq$d is zero." 
 
Could anyone explains quote? If possible with an example.
 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a Boolean function $f$ is represented as a polynomial of degree $< d$ in indeterminates $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ over the binary field $\mathbb F_2$, where $m \ge d$.  Each term must involve fewer than $d$ indeterminates, so there is at least one indeterminate it does not contain.  Thus

$$ \sum_{(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in \mathbb F_2^m} f(x_1,\ldots,x_m) = 0 $$
because the summation of a term over an indeterminate not present is $0$ (i.e.
$\sum_{x \in \mathbb F_2} t = t+ t = 0$).

Comment: Could you check the question again?